# Perl "HTTP::cookies"" with "LWP::UserAgent" error: "does not look like a Netscape cookies file"

Tags: macos, perl, http, cookies

I'm trying to do the equivalent of `curl --cookie cookies.txt "https://foo.example.org/bar"` in a `Perl` script.  I have a cookies file that I believe is in Netscape format (tab delimited) that works fine with `curl`.  `HTTP::cookies` complains:

> cookies.txt does not look like a Netscape cookies file at
>   /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.10.0/HTTP/Cookies/netscape.pm line 21,
>    line 1.

My script is just a stub for testing:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
use HTTP::Cookies::Netscape;
my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies::Netscape->new
                  ( 'file' => 'cookies.txt', );  
my $url = 'http://www.google.com/';
my $response = $ua->get( $url );
print "Return: $response->status_line\n";
```

The cookies.txt file actually starts with a comment:

```
# This content may be pasted into a cookies.txt file and used by wget
```

But I tried deleting the comment and got the same exact error.  The cookies.txt file has Unix style line endings.

Answer (score 1):

Arg!

Turns out that, while `curl` is happy with the file, the `HTTP::Cookes::Netscape` module wants the first line to be

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
```

I added that, and now it seems happy.

(I found the [module source code](https://github.com/brad/Misterhouse/blob/master/lib/site/HTTP/Cookies/Netscape.pm) and searched for the error message.)

Comment: Can also find the source code on metacpan or cpan: [HTTP::Cookies::Netscape](https://metacpan.org/source/GAAS/HTTP-Cookies-6.01/lib/HTTP/Cookies/Netscape.pm)

Comment: Personally, I think it's a bug that `HTTP::Cookes::Netscape` rejects a cookies file that doesn't have a specific comment as the first line.  Much better would be to check if it seems to have tab-separated values.  If it is going to check comments (which it shouldn't) then the error message should say "Cookie file rejected: first line must be ..." or some such.

Comment: Agreed, error messages should be more explicit.  Unfortunately, this is a fairly common flaw, enough so that the first thing I do is examine the source as well to determine the full context of an error.